# Unicode and more information about errors in Django

Tags: django, python-2.7, unicode, ascii

I'm newbee. I use Django ==1.7.5 with python-2.7. When I execute command

```
django-admin makemessages -a
```

I receive an error:

```
'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 374-378 ordinal not in range(128)
```

Is there a way in Django to print out more information about errors? How can I find the file with wrong characters? Traceback don't give the name of this file. I checked all templates and other files but found nothing.

I have `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` everywhere and my model has `def __unicode__(self)` method.

Comment: Try running `export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8` in the shell before you run the django-admin command.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue might be where you convert the unicode to ascii or whatever format you are trying to convert it to. Keep everything you have already in place and go over the code where it does this and isolate and test it separately to see if it produces the result you want.

I think I might be a bit vague in the answer, this should have been a comment however I do not have 50 reputation points yet to make one.